# Cycle Sequence Limits

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ be the following sequences that repeat in cycles of four:
$s_n=(0,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,...)$
$t_n=(2,1,1,0,2,1,1,0,...)$

Find:

> $$\text{lim inf} (s_n + t_n)$$
>   $$\text {lim sup} (s_n + t_n)$$
>   $$\text {lim sup} (s_nt_n)$$

So I would think we would take the inf and sup for $s_n$ and $t_n$ and then add? So inf $s_n = 0$ and inf $t_n=0$ so $\text {lim inf}(s_n+t_n)=0+0=$?

Comment: $s_n+t_n$ is a completely new sequence. Write up what that sequence is, then do $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ on that. Same for $s_nt_n$.

Comment: @Arthur is $\text {lim inf}(s_n+t_n)$ not the same as $\text{lim inf} s_n + \text{lim inf} t_n$?

Comment: No, not at all. Do what I said in my above comment and see what happens. It is, however, possible to prove in general that $\liminf(s_n + t_n) \geq \liminf s_n + \liminf t_n$.

Comment: I don't believe I know how to add two sequence together then. Is it similar to $s_n+t_n=(0,1,2,1,...)+(2,1,1,0,...)=(2,2,3,1...)$? Then $\text{lim inf}  (s_n+t_n)=1$

Comment: That's exactly it: adding term by term. For the last one, you're asked to multiply instead of add, but otherwise it's the same.